# How to format the file using awk and sed or perl script to get a desired file

Tags: perl, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a file like below:

```
101 start_time
102 start_time
101 end_time
103 start_time
103 end_time
102 end_time
104 start_time
104 end_time
102 start_time
102 end_time
```

I want to have a output file like below:

```
101 start_time end_time
102 start_time end_time
103 start_time end_time
104 start_time end_time
102 start_time end_time
```

With basic sed or awk operation or with perl how it can be done? Please help!

Comment: `grep -v end | sed 's/$/ end_time/' | sort | uniq` (or something like that, I didn't test it).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
awk '$1 in a{ print $1, a[$1], $2; delete a[$1]; next} {a[$1] = $2}' input
```

Comment: @sputnick I'm not sure I understand your comment.  The OP wants duplicate lines in the output, and this provides them, as desired.

Comment: Doh, I was reading too fast, I go away with my wrong response ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -anE'say "@F end_time" if $F[1] eq "start_time"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Follows a Perl approach.

- Note 1: not very well written, but it works properly
- Note 2: my answer is based on the consideration that by "start_time" and "end_time" you don't refer literally to a string, but to some sort of timestamp or whatever

There you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @waiting; #here we will keep track of the order
my %previous; #here we will save previous rows that still can't be printed
open (my $IN,'<','file.txt') or die "$!"; #assuming that your data is in file.txt
while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id,$time)=split/ /;
    if (exists $previous{$id}) { #if this is the end_time
        $previous{$id}->[1]=$time;
        if ($waiting[0]==$id) { #if we are not waiting for another row's end_time
            my $count=0;
            for (@waiting) { #print anything you have available
                last if !defined $previous{$_}->[1];
                print join(' ',$x,@{$previous{$_}}),"\n";
                delete $previous{$_};
                $count++;
            }
            shift @waiting for 1..$count; 
        }
    }
    else { #if this is the start_time
        push @waiting,$id;
        $previous{$id}=[$time,undef];
    }
}
close $IN;
```